# How do I implement select of hero in canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have got Hero to canvas. How do i select it and open context menu?

[image: hero]
[image: select hero]

I may added listener only to canvas, becuse class Image not contains this method.

Simple code:

```
context.drawImage(hero, heroX, heroY);
context.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-in";
context.drawImage(mask, heroX, heroY);
context.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-over";

function getElementPosition(obj) {
    var curleft = 0,
        curtop = 0;
    if (obj.offsetParent) {
        do {
            curleft += obj.offsetLeft;
            curtop += obj.offsetTop;
        } while (obj = obj.offsetParent);
        return {
            x: curleft,
            y: curtop
        };
    }
    return undefined;
}

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(evt) {
    var mousePos = getMousePos(canvas, evt);
    var message = 'Mouse position: ' + mousePos.x + ',' + mousePos.y;
    var elementPos = getElementPosition(hero); //doesn't work
    alert(elementPos.x);
}, false);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store the hero's coordinates and check for them in the mousemove callback. `offsetLeft` and `offsetTop` work for DOM elements, not for pixels drawn on a canvas.

Not possible to give you a more accurate answer from the code you provided. `heroX` and `heroY` *look* like something you should use, but again, without seeing what they are, it's impossible to tell.

Comment: It's complicated decision. :) Is it possible add addEventListener for class Image?

Comment: Only if you use it as an image DOM element on top of the canvas (meaning: not drawing it on the canvas). Otherwise, no, you'd have to do some math. :)

Comment: "an image element on top of the canvas" - is this means using DOM elements? Example, may i added tag <img src="">.. and used it? getElementById('newMyImage').addEventListener? I understand correctly? :)

Comment: Yes, an absolutely positioned image would work the best here. Though I think it might make everything more complicated in the future as opposed to just storing the hero's coordinates.

Comment: I understand. :) Thank you.